# Finding common words in given two strings

Tags: c, string, char, malloc

I came across a question where we need find the common words in the given two strings. The description of the question:

> OVERVIEW: Given two strings, find the words that are common to both the strings.
>   E.g.: Input: "one two three", "two three five".  Output: "two", "three".
>
> INPUTS: Two strings.
>
> OUTPUT: common words in two given strings, return 2D array of strings.
>
> ERROR CASES: Return NULL for invalid inputs.
>
> NOTES: If there are no common words, return NULL.

I have gone through the question and started solving it in Visual Studio 2013.
where it has many test cases.

Here is my code:

```
int ispresent(char*a, char *b)
{
    int m = strlen(a);
    int n = strlen(b);
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i <= n - m; i++){             
        for ( j = 0; j<m; j++){
            if (a[j] != b[i + j]) break;
        }
        if (j == m)
            return 1;
   }
    return 0;
}
char ** commonWords(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    if (str1 != NULL&&str2 != NULL)
    {
        char **res = (char**)malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            res[i] = (char*)malloc(31 * sizeof(char));
        char *a = (char*)malloc(31 * sizeof(char));
        int k = 0, j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++, j++)
        {
            if (str1[i] != ' ')
                a[j] = str1[i];
            if (str1[i] == ' ' || str1[i] == '\0')
            {
                a[j] = '\0';
                if (ispresent(a, str2))
                    res[k++] = a;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

But I am getting a run time error here :
The program has terminated unexpectedly

Can I get get any solution please?

And I have got a suggestion that it is a possible duplicate 
 But My code is not same as that.. I am not asking the question> I am asking suggestion to my code

Comment: use a debugger, that' s the best way.

Comment: Even I have been trying that .But it stopped

Comment: debugger will stop hopefully near the point where your code is incorrect or shows which array is not properly initialized.

Comment: duplicate of this guy's homework :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043210/given-two-strings-c-program-to-find-the-words-that-are-common-to-both-the-strin

Comment: that guy is one of the member in our course @Spikolynn

Comment: @Madhusudanchowdary his question is from last year, but the answer he got seems promising.

Comment: You have a pointer array of length 10 but you only allocate memory for the first 3 of those 10 pointers. Don't use magic numbers! And how does the calling function know how many of the elements were used?

Comment: In all my test cases the number is below 10 So i used 10 over .And It is not a magical number :@WeatherVane

Comment: He is our Senior @Spikolynn First try to answer my question if you know. my proccess of solving is different from him.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given Two Strings, C Program to find the words that are common to both the strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043210/given-two-strings-c-program-to-find-the-words-that-are-common-to-both-the-strin)

Comment: What guarantees `n - m` is a positive value? Why not simply tokenize the first string and save the results in an allocated *pointer-to-pointer-to-char* and then tokenize the second strings comparing words as you go. At that point you know the number of words that match, so allocate/copy only those that match to a new `char **` object, free all prior allocations and return the new object.

Comment: thankyou @DavidC.Rankin I will try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with this exercise you supposed to learn these things:

1. do not use magic numbers, use #define instead
2. always check pointers for NULL if function can return NULL
3. check for boundaries, make sure your code behaves reasonable if input is too long
4. do not forget free memory you allocated
5. use library functions when possible

Here an example how you it can be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_WORD_LEN    30
#define MAX_WORDS       10


char ** commonWords(char *str1, char *str2)
{
if (str1 != NULL && str2 != NULL)
{
    char a[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
    char **res = (char**)calloc(MAX_WORDS+1, sizeof(char*));
    if(!res) return NULL;

    int k = 0, j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str1[i] != '\0' && k < MAX_WORDS; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] != ' ' && j < MAX_WORD_LEN)
            a[j++] = str1[i];
        if (str1[i] == ' ' || str1[i] == '\0') {
            a[j] = '\0';
            if (strstr(str2,a)) {
                res[k++] = strdup(a);
            }
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
char **cw = commonWords("one two three", "two three five");
if(cw) {
    for(int i=0; cw[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s ",cw[i]);
        free(cw[i]);
    }
    free(cw);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Please remember that you can learn only if you practice ;)

Comment: Thanks you for your solution . It if working fine for some inputs ....if the input is given as str1="         ", str2="adc sbgj aka" .This will not work and for the strings with no common words also doesn't work that i can do it .Thanks for your hardwork.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution with little changes. and thanks for the people who have contributed to this .
this solution had run for all my test cases :

Solution :

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #define SIZE 10
    #define WORD_SIZE 31 
    int ispresent(char*a, char *b)
    {
        int m = strlen(a);
        int n = strlen(b);
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i <= n - m; i++){
            for (j = 0; j<m; j++){
                if (a[j] != b[i + j]) break;
            }
            if (j == m)
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    char ** commonWords(char *str1, char *str2)
    {
        if (str1 != NULL&&str2 != NULL)
        {
            char **res = (char**)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char*));
            for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++)
                res[p] = (char*)malloc(WORD_SIZE * sizeof(char));
            char *a = (char*)malloc(WORD_SIZE * sizeof(char));
            int k = 0, j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++)
            {
                if (str1[i] != ' ')
                    a[j++] = str1[i];
                if (str1[i] == ' ' || str1[i] == '\0')
                {
                    a[j++] = '\0';
                    if (ispresent(a, str2)&&a!="\0")
                        res[k++] = strdup(a);
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
            for (int x = 0; x <=k; x++)
                if (res[x] == "\0"||k==0||strlen(res[x])<=1)
                    return NULL;
            return res;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

and the test cases for the program that I had run in Visual Studio are

```
test.spec file:

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "../src/commonWords.cpp"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace spec
{
    TEST_CLASS(commonWordsSpec)
    {
    public:

        bool strcmp(char *str1, char *str2) {
            while (*str1 && *str2) {
                if (*str1 != *str2) {
                    return false;
                }
                str1++;
                str2++;
            }
            return !*str1 && !*str2;
        }

        bool compare(char expected[][31], int count, char **actual) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                bool found = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                    if (strcmp(expected[i], actual[j])) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        TEST_METHOD(nullInput)
        {
            Assert::IsNull(commonWords(NULL, NULL), L"Common Words null 
       check failed.", LINE_INFO());
        }

        TEST_METHOD(stringsWithSpaces)
        {
            char *str1 = "       ";
            char *str2 = " who what";
            Assert::IsNull(commonWords(str1, str2), L"No common words check failed.", LINE_INFO());
        }

        TEST_METHOD(noCommonWordsInput)
        {
            char *str1 = "the are all is well";
            char *str2 = " who what";
            Assert::IsNull(commonWords(str1, str2), L"No common words check failed.", LINE_INFO());
        }

        TEST_METHOD(commonWordsInput)
        {
            char *str1 = "the are all is well";
            char *str2 = "is who the";
            char expected[2][31] = { { "the" }, { "is" } };
            char **res = commonWords(str1, str2);
            Assert::IsTrue(compare(expected, 2, res), L"Common Words positive check failed.", LINE_INFO());
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, one easy and logical approach is simply to *tokenize* the words in the first string using `strtok` (or whatever method you prefer). Allocate storage for each word found and store the words in a temporary `char **tmp` variable. The *tokenize* the second string, and compare each word from the first string with each token from the second. If they match, add a pointer to the word in the first array as a pointer in your `results` array. (you need not allocate additional storage, as all your `char **results` variable will hold are pointers to the memory already allocated in `tmp`. (just don't free `tmp` before you are finished using `result`)

Since you know how many comparisons resulting in a match, outputting each of the words in `result` is a simple matter.

To put all the pieces together you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { NPT = 10, MAXC = 32 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *s1 = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : (char[]) { 
                        "My dog has fleas and my cat has none." },
         *s2 = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : (char[]) { 
                        "My frog likes the dog and the rat like the cat. "},
         *delim = " \t\n.,",
         **result = malloc (NPT * sizeof *result),
         **tmp = malloc (NPT * sizeof *tmp);
    int n = 0, r = 0;

    if (!result || !tmp) { /*... handle mem error ...*/ }

    printf ("finding common words between:\n s1: %s\n s2: %s\n", s1, s2);

    /* tokenize all words in s1, save in tmp */
    for (char *p = strtok (s1, delim); p && n < NPT; p = strtok (NULL, delim))
        tmp[n++] = strdup (p);

    /* tokenize all words in s2, compare against words in tmp, save result */
    for (char *p = strtok (s2, delim); p && r < n; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (strcmp (p, tmp[i]) == 0)
                result[r++] = tmp[i];
    }

    if (r) printf ("\ncommon words:\n"); else printf ("\nno common words.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        printf ("  %s\n", result[i]);

    free (result);      /* free all allocated memory */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free (tmp[i]);
    free (tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** `strtok` modifies the strings passed as arguments, so a compound-literal was used to insure `s1` and `s2` where character arrays capable of modification.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_common_words
finding common words between:
 s1: My dog has fleas and my cat has none.
 s2: My frog likes the dog and the rat like the cat.

common words:
  My
  dog
  and
  cat


$ ./bin/str_common_words "a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" \
"a quick greed frog jumps over the lazy bog"
finding common words between:
 s1: a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
 s2: a quick greed frog jumps over the lazy bog

common words:
  a
  quick
  jumps
  over
  the
  lazy
```

An example where no common words exist.

```
$ ./bin/str_common_words "my flea and bat" "your snake & rat"
finding common words between:
 s1: my flea and bat
 s2: your snake & rat

no common words.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: This is fine .Actually we were given this as an assignment and they told us not to create any extra strings except result string and not to use string inbuilt functions .even most of my friends solved like as said by you so I tried not to tokenize works..And thanks for taking effort on my question @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: but you did it in a different manner .I get to know many things from your solution .Thank you

Comment: Sure, you can use two pointers to walk down the string just as easy as you can use `strtok`. (using the exact same logical layout) All you are doing is locating spaces and taking the words. Using a `startp` and `endp` pointers, just search forward with `endp` until a `' '` is found, then use `tmp[i] = malloc (endp - startp); strncpy (tmp[i], startp, endp - 1 - startp); tmp[i][endp - 1 - startp] = 0;` The strings I provided were just default values, if you give any two strings on the command line, that is what is compared.